# Laravel where is the request bound into the container?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I know Laravel binds the request into the container since the helper method resolves it from the container like so:

```
function request($key = null, $default = null)
{
    if (is_null($key)) {
        return app('request');
    }

    if (is_array($key)) {
        return app('request')->only($key);
    }

    return app('request')->input($key, $default);
}
```

At what exact point is the request being bound into the container though? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laravel request object is bound and rebound from multiple service providers.

You can find this in the Laravel framework as below:

[Kernel.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7212b1e9620c36bf806e444f6931cf5f379c68ff/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php#L140), [SetRequestForConsole.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7212b1e9620c36bf806e444f6931cf5f379c68ff/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/SetRequestForConsole.php#L18) and [AuthServiceProvider.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7212b1e9620c36bf806e444f6931cf5f379c68ff/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthServiceProvider.php#L84)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the Kernel instance where it happened. Cheers!